# How can I render jobs from company Linkedin on my company website?

Tags: json, linkedin-api

I need a way to get jobs from my company linkedin e.g [Google](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_C=1441%2C17876832%2C791962%2C2374003%2C18950635%2C16140%2C10440912&geoId=92000000) and display these jobs on my website. Linkedin docs for this are very bad and I couldn't find a way to get this JSON with specific jobs for my company. I checked network tab looking for some request which could show me jobs but it seems that is all rendered on their side.

Comment: you need to consume Linkedin API

Comment: this might help you  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api